# How to create a "assign button" texbox in visual studio / wpf / c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, input

I have just started coding using Visual Studio. I have created a wpf project and got it to do some simple stuff, so far so good.

Now I want to create a textbox that acts like the "assign key/button" fields you find in the options menus of games, etc. Essentially when the user clicks on the textbox, a message will be shown prompting the user to press any key. Once the user presses any key (and it turns out it wasn't ESC), that key is stored in the textbox (no input cursor in the textbox, no pressing enter/return to confirm, etc. just waiting for the next keyboard input).

At a later point I want to use that stored value to check if it matches kayboard input, and trigger the corresponding action then.

Could anybody please point me in the right direction? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Make the textbox readonly and when the user hits the key while it is focused, just print that key to textbox:

```
private void textbox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (textbox.IsFocused && e.Key != Key.Escape)
    {
        textbox.Text = e.Key.ToString();
    }
}
```

And in XAML:

```
<TextBox x:Name="textbox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" KeyUp="textbox_KeyUp" IsReadOnly="True"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That is a rather "oldschool" way to do it from a ui/feel perspective, a more modern way I want to emulate is to have a small popup that waits for a key to be pressed, but with your solution I can do some initial testing and work from there.

Comment: There is no built in input dialog in WPF. Alternatively, you can create custom input dialog as separate window with text box and use the same approach.